# Android tablets change app name in action bar with image

Tags: android-actionbar, android

As the title states, is there a way to hide application name in the action bar and insert instead a png image?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action bar will by default use your activity or application icon. You can add an `android:logo` attribute to your `<activity>` in the manifest with an alternate image, and that will be used automatically.

To get rid of the title, use `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`, called on your `ActionBar`.

Comment: Ok, but I was asking another thing: how to use an image instead of title!

Comment: To use an image instead of a title, you **follow the instructions in my answer**. You use `android:logo` to define the image, and you get rid of the text title using `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`.